# What is the Most Succinct Way to Change a String Column to an Integer Column

Tags: mysql, string, integer

I currently have a database that uses a calculated value for sorting. The calculation is cached in a string column, but the value is guaranteed to be a natural number. I'm trying to change the column's data type to speed up sorting, but I can't think of a quick solution.

My current plan is something along the lines of:

```
ALTER TABLE
    items
ADD COLUMN isort INT;
```

followed by:

```
UPDATE
    items
SET
    isort = CAST(sort AS DECIMAL(11, 0));
```

and finally:

```
ALTER TABLE
    items
DROP COLUMN sort;

ALTER TABLE
    items
RENAME COLUMN isort TO sort;
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Seems like a big fuss about a pretty straightforward change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the column to a different type

```
ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY col1 INTEGER NOT NULL;
```